# Perl: Sort Array after a Hash-value

Tags: perl, hash

Is there a "Perl-ish" way to sort a array of hashes after a hash-val?

```
my @l = ({k1 => "1", k2 => "one"}, {k1 => "2", k2 => "two"}, 
     {k1 => "3", k2 => "three"});

foreach (@l)
{
  print "\n" . $_->{k1} . ", " . $_->{k2};
}
```

The order I get is the order I inserted (what else...). But I'd like to sort it after a hash-value.
I can imagine the algorithmic-way. But I am asking about a maybe already existing function or something.

Thanks!

Comment: Always use strict; use warnings; in your code.

Comment: Your are 100% right. But I think it is not necessary for that sample. It is just to describe the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sort by the value behind the `k1` key, you can do as follows.

```
my @sorted = sort { $a->{k1} <=> $b->{k1} } @l;
```

The variables `$a` and `$b` are reserved special vars for [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html). If your list-items are references, you can just use them as such.

Output with [Data::Printer](http://p3rl.org/Data::Printer):

```
[
    [0] {
        k1   1,
        k2   "one"
    },
    [1] {
        k1   2,
        k2   "two"
    },
    [2] {
        k1   3,
        k2   "three"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, thats the perl'ish I was looking for ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`@list = sort { $a->{'k1'} <=> $b->{'k1'} } @l;`